# How to use docker buildx bake to build docker compose containers for both linux/armv7 and linux/amd64

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have developed a primarily raspberry pi app in Python that uses Redis as its local cache so naturally I turned to docker compose to define all my services i.e. redis and my app. I am using Docker Hub private repository to host my container. But I do not get how to use the `docker buildx bake` command to target linux/armv7 platform as `--platform` flag is not part of `bake`

All the examples that the Docker team has shown use the simple `docker buildx` command which cannot be run for compose files.

My docker-compose.yml file is defined as:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine

  app:
    image: dockerhub/repository
    build: gateway
    restart: always
```

Dockerfile:

```
# set base image (Host OS)
FROM python:3.8-slim

# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /run

# copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY src/ .

# command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "-u", "run.py" ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Build with `docker buildx` , push to the registry and run with docker-compose (without `build:`).

Comment: @KlausD. Wouldn't that require me to create/copy my docker-compose file to the rpi? If yes is there no way to run apps which depend on multiple other services when trying to cross compile?

Comment: I expected that you have the docker-compose file where you run the containers. You can theoretically use it for building only but then the `restart` does not make sense.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for the guidance, this is my first deployment via docker so I am just getting the hang of things. Yeah, I have copied the compose file over to my rpi and it works great. The only thing is that the redis container now runs as a separate container from my app container according to docker ps while on my dev machine they both run in one. I am guessing this is going to cause trouble if I provide redis config files in my app. Is this the intended deployment workflow in such cases?

Comment: It is completely normal that the service run in different containers in `docker-compose`. If you have trouble accessing redis, set `hostname:` for the service and use that hostname in the config.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for all the help, its working great now!

Answer (score 1):

you can supply platform parameter under key xbake as mentioned below. (reference document: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_bake/)

```
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  addon:
    image: ct-addon:bar
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        CT_ECR: foo
        CT_TAG: bar
      x-bake:
        tags:
          - ct-addon:foo
          - ct-addon:alp
        platforms:
          - linux/amd64
          - linux/arm64
        cache-from:
          - user/app:cache
          - type=local,src=path/to/cache
        cache-to: type=local,dest=path/to/cache
        pull: true

  aws:
    image: ct-fake-aws:bar
    build:
      dockerfile: ./aws.Dockerfile
      args:
        CT_ECR: foo
        CT_TAG: bar
      x-bake:
        secret:
          - id=mysecret,src=./secret
          - id=mysecret2,src=./secret2
        platforms: linux/arm64
        output: type=docker
        no-cache: true
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).